# Nginx 403 Forbidden with pimcore

Tags: nginx, pimcore

I'm trying to install pimcore with nginx. I've copied the folder to /var/www/html. But when I tried to access localhost/pimcore, I got 403 Forbidden error

**/var/log/nginx/error.log**

```
2016/10/14 20:43:42 [error] 10888#10888: *9 directory index of "/var/www/html/pimcore/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /pimcore/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

**ls -al /var/www/html**

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root     4096 Oct 14 18:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root     4096 Oct 14 18:57 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      612 Oct 14 18:28 index.nginx-debian.html
drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 13 19:15 pimcore
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Have you recursively owned the `pimcore` folder for `www-data` user?

Comment: I've used `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data pimcore` and restart nginx, but still got 403 forbidden

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting the directory `pimcore/` but there is no indication whether a directory listing should be displayed, or if an index file has to be used.  Adding `index index.php` might help.

Comment: When I advise to add `index index.php` I mean to add this in the Nginx configuration file otherwise Nginx is not aware of `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Pimcore is not intended to run from a subdirectory. Additionally, you seemingly haven't configured nginx (and php) for Pimcore at all, since the `.conf` you posted is lacking the interesting parts, which are included from the `conf.d` and `sites-enabled` subdirectories.

Please go through the [installation guide](https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/master/docs/Development_Documentation/01_Getting_Started/00_Installation.md).